# Render view with data in Node JS [NO FRAMEWORK]

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have an end point called `/watch` that get data and should return page with filled data. This app is not express just a http server

and the template ejs view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div>Data</p>
            <ul>
        <% arr.forEach(function(elem) { %>
            <li><%= elem %></li>
        <% }); %>
            </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there any equivalent in node js

```
res.render('index', {
        arr: data,
    });
```

This is a snippet from the server code

```
const server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{

const parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url,true);

const path = parsedUrl.pathname;
const trimmedPath = path.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g,'')

if(trimmedPath == "watch"){

    var data = await GetData();

            // here where i need to stuck sending the ejs template with data

}

})
```

Comment: Please add your server code.  I would think it would be something along the lines of `res.send(ejs.render("<%template%>", {scope}));`.

Comment: i updated to question with a snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to send the String that `ejs.render()` creates.  Consider the barebones example that EJS shows: [EJS#Get Started](http://ejs.co/#install) and combine that with the barebones HTTP server that node provides [an example](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_clienterror) for:

```
const http = require("http");
const ejs = require("ejs");

const template = "<div><%= people.join(',');%></div>";
const people = ["bob", "sue", "steve"];

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.end(ejs.render(template, {people}));
});

server.listen(8081, () => {
    console.log("Listening on 8081");
});
```

The network response I get back is:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8081 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8081
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 27 Aug 2018 17:10:01 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Length: 24
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
<div>bob,sue,steve</div>
```

Comment: thanks alot that went so smooth

`let template = fs.readFileSync( __dirname + "/public/index.html").toString();
            res.end(ejs.render(template, {data}));
`